# How to send back custom HTTP headers from my Perl server?

Tags: linux, perl, http-headers, server

I am writing a Perl HTTP server using [`HTTP::Daemon`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP::Daemon). My Perl client is sending a `HEAD` request to the server to get the content length of the file which IO have to `GET` later.

My problem is that I am not able to generate a custom header and send it back to the client.

I can send back basic HTTP headers using `$c->send_basic_header`, but as soon as I try to send specific headers using `$c->send_header( $field1, $value1, $field2, $value2, ... )` it does not work.

I am not able to understand what is the problem.

The headers which I am trying to send is

```
$c->send_header('Content-Type','image/jpeg','Cotent-Length','56360','Accept-Ranges','bytes')
```

I am new to Perl, so please help me understand how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean by *"it does not work"*?

Comment: It does not work mean that my client is not getting these values in the response off the head request.

Comment: Okay, so it is getting the basic headers (`Server` and `Date`) but nothing else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your code, but do you realise that you need to `send_basic_header` *as well* as `send_header`?

Your code should look like this

```
$c->send_basic_header;
$c->send_header(
    'Content-Type'   => 'image/jpeg',
    'Content-Length' => '56360',
    'Accept-Ranges'  => 'bytes',
);
$c->send_crlf;
```